# Devise shared link redirecting to other controller/ action from the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Recently i have noticed that clicking on Devise's shared links such as `forgot password?` and `Didn't receive confirmation instructions?` is causing a subscriber form on the footer to get submitted automatically and ultimately throwing an error on browser like:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Passwords#new 
No route matches {:action=>"subscribe", :controller=>"devise/home"}
```

and error on console are like:

```
Started GET "/users/password/new" for ::1 at 2016-01-29 23:57:39 +0530
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 588ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"subscribe", :controller=>"devise/home"}):
    31:       </div><!--col-md-* end-->
    32:       <div class="col-md-4 mob-mgbtm-foo">
    33:         <div class="foo-hd">Subcribe to our Newsletter</div>
    34:         <%= form_tag({controller:"home", action: "subscribe"}, {class: 'form-inline'}) do %>
    35:           <div class="form-group">
    36:             <input name="email" type="email" class="foo-intxt form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
    37:           </div>
  app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb:34:in `_app_views_layouts__footer_html_erb___1185320491891532297_70313812020980'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1232363268137916075_70313747392400'


  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (11.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (145.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (72.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (239.3ms)


Started GET "/users/password/new" for ::1 at 2016-01-29 23:57:41 +0530
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 557ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"subscribe", :controller=>"devise/home"}):
    31:       </div><!--col-md-* end-->
    32:       <div class="col-md-4 mob-mgbtm-foo">
    33:         <div class="foo-hd">Subcribe to our Newsletter</div>
    34:         <%= form_tag({controller:"home", action: "subscribe"}, {class: 'form-inline'}) do %>
    35:           <div class="form-group">
    36:             <input name="email" type="email" class="foo-intxt form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
    37:           </div>
  app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb:34:in `_app_views_layouts__footer_html_erb___1185320491891532297_70313813434860'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1232363268137916075_70313747392400'


  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (10.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (94.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (86.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/abhinaykumar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (188.4ms)
```

for some unknown reason, clicking on `forgot password?` is getting redirected to `devise/home` as can be seen in the error.

here the is form on `footer.html.erb`

```
    <%= form_tag({controller:"home", action: "subscribe"}, {class: 'form-inline'}) do %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" type="email" class="foo-intxt form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="org-btn btn">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </button>
        <% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: :registrations, sessions: "sessions",
                      omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}

resources :guests
post 'subscribe', to: 'home#subscribe'
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  # Home page
  def index
  end

  def about
  end


  def subscribe
    AdminMailer.subscribe(params[:email]).deliver_now
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank you for Signing up for newsletter, will keep you posted!!'
  end

  def faq
  end
end
```

Also, I am not sure why error is getting rendered multiple times on the terminal.

Comment: You are missing a route for subscriptions, update your answer with the routes.rb file

Comment: @Cyzanfar even i think i am messing up with routes but not sure. btw just updated with `routes.rb` file

Comment: What about the controller could you past that in too

Comment: @Cyzanfar yeah just updated the question with `home_controller.rb` file

Comment: Are you usnig `turbolinks` or `jquery_ujs`?  I suspect one of them is causing multiple forms to be submitted.  Check that nowhere in your JS code is something like `$("form").submit()` because that will submit all forms on the page at once.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh yeah thats true but I am pretty sure I am not submitting form through JS, besides `forgot password?` is a link to `/users/password/new` which is then getting redirected to '/subscribe'. I can see devise is trying to access `devise/home` there

Comment: You could try naming  your route `post 'subscribe', to: 'home#subscribe', as: :subscribe`, and then in your form, try using that for your url `<%= form_tag(subscribe_path, ...`. Alternatively, you could try `'/subscribe'` for your route, if you don't want to name the route. Either option should make it less ambiguous as to where to find the home controller.

Comment: @MichaelCruz yeah apparently form was not able to find the right controller, changing the it to the `subscribe_path` solved the issue. even though now it works, I am still confused about `forgot password?` leading to the subscribe path.

Comment: It wasn't actually taking you there. It was just trying to render the forgot password form with that footer and wasn't able to build the link, because it couldn't resolve the route for the link.

Comment: @MichaelCruz Yep thanks for explaining it. could you please post an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is trying to render the forgot password page with the footer, but when it tries to build that link in the footer, it is looking for a controller called home within the devise namespace, which doesn't exist.

There are two ways you could solve the ambiguity:

**1. Use a named route**
Change your route `post 'subscribe', to: 'home#subscribe', as: :subscribe`, and then in your form, try using that for your url `<%= form_tag(subscribe_path, ....`

**2. Using your current route**
Alternatively, you could try `'/subscribe'` for your route, if you don't want to name the route.